# GTK Text to entry

Tags: c, gtk

After having a look at firefox's history window, i saw something which i want to implement to my own entry:

[image: http://s17.postimage.org/vetecz71r/history.png]

How can I make the default text in the entry faded like that?

Comment: That's called "cue text" or "cue banner" by the way

Comment: good to know how its called,i will use that term now (:

Answer (score 6):

In GTK+ it's called [placeholder text](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-placeholder-text), available in GtkEntry since GTK+ 3.2.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation for GTK versions earlier than 3.2:

https://github.com/ptomato/gnome-inform7/blob/master/src/placeholder-entry.c